# Java Sonar make it transient or serializable spring jpa

Tags: java, jpa, transient

```
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

   @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company; // here sonar complains about transient

}
```

My Company is:

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @Column
    private Long id;


    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<User> users;

}
```

My question is, how i should deal with this? If i put private transient Company my application won't start , i get errors : mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property. How can i deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be `List` which doesn’t extend `Serializable`. You can solve it by using `ArrayList` which instead extends it.